# Populate markers in leaflet with tweets and tweet location using python

Tags: python, leaflet, twitter, folium

I am iterating over twitter using python, the user inputs a topic to search for on twitter and then the location to view on the map in leaflet. The leaflet map is created automatically in the browser. How do I get the marker to show up at the tweet location assuming there is coordinates associated with the tweet which in a lot of cases does not happen. Below is the code I think you need to look into this. Suggestions? Using folium, webbrowser, os, geopy, TwitterSearch modules here.

```
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        tweetText = ( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) )
        print tweetText
        if tweet['place'] is not None:
            (lat, lng) = geo(tweet['place']['full_name'])
            print 'And they said it from (' + str(lat) +', ' +str(lng)+')'
        else:
            print "And their place wasn't specified..."
Here is the piece for the marker using the folium module

for tweetLocation in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
    folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup='tweetText').add_to(mapLeafletPython)
```

I originally had the for tweetLocation loop in the for tweet in ts.search...(tso): part but it wouldn't work. Have them pulled apart doesn't help either.

Here is some documentation for folium:

http://folium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

also (looking through this now...)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/folium

Let me know if you have questions, I'd be happy to provide additional details.

Answer (score 1):

```
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        tweetText = ( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) ).encode("ascii", "ignore")
        print tweetText
        if tweet['place'] is not None:
            (lat, lng) = geo(tweet['place']['full_name'])
            tw = tweet['text']
            user= tweet['user']['screen_name']
            folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup= user + " said " + tw).add_to(mapLeafletPython)
            print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % (user, tw) + 'And they said it from (' + str(lat) +', ' +str(lng)+')').encode("ascii", "ignore")
        else:
            print "And their place wasn't specified..."
```